# Heros of the Rabbanan Holidays and Ultimately losing out

Tags: chanuka, purim, historical-figures

Why is it that both Purim and Chanukah the heroes of their stories ended up losing out?
That is, Esther had no Jewish descendants as she married a non-Jew (though her son was Jewish according to Halacha) but her son did not marry a Jewish woman so his children were not Jewish.
Meanwhile Haman's children learned Torah in Bnei Brak.
As [the Gemara states](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.96b.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

"מבני בניו של המן למדו תורה בבני ברק"

(Among the descendants of Haman were those who studied Torah in Bnei Brak).

Then The Maccabees were killed out, and the Gemara says *whoever says I am from the Children of the Maccabees is a slave or a liar*, as [the Gemara states](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.3b.14?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi):

כל האומר מבית חשמונאי אני, או שהוא עבד או שהוא רמאי

The heroes are the biggest losers and these are our Rabbinic holidays. Why is this and what is the connection?

Comment: Well, it took around a hundred years, but the Maccabee/Hasmoneans pretty much did themselves in by infighting, allowing Herod's machinations to put himself and the Romans in charge...If Aristobulus and Hyrcanus had a united front together there would've been no Herod...maybe..but the Maccabee brothers themselves and the first John Hyrcanus did a glorious job of restoring Jewish nationhood, and deserve to be celebrated.

Comment: Did Esther not have children from a previous marriage? Also since when is she obligated in Pru Urvu that we care if she has kids? Also isn't Judaism passed on matrilineally?

Comment: Moshe's descendant made and worshipped idols. As did many of David's. I don't know why this is so surprising. How do you know Esther didn't have daughters that stayed Jewish? Or sons from another previous marriage? Etc. The Pesukim tell us nothing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Rabbi J.B. Soloveitchik  addresses an issue similar to this in his essay "Catharsis"

Comment: You make a good observation here. In my opinion, it comes to teach us that you could be the greatest tzaddik or heroic savior of your people, but there's nothing "for-sure" about chinuch and how one's child may grow up.